# Anylogic: How to model technical availability of machines?

Tags: model, simulation, anylogic

I'm trying to model a production line with 4 consecutive machines (source > buffer1 > machine1 > buffer2 > machine2 > ...). Each machine has its own specific technical availability (probability of a breakdown) and - in case of a breakdown - a specific duration of the breakdown. The duration of the downtimes are exponentially distributed.
Example: Machine 1 has a technical availability of 90% and an average downtime of 2 hours.

- Is it more useful to model the machines as blocks "queue + delay" or as block "service"?
- How can I model the **technical availability** with the **distributed downtime**?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SOF,

Use a `Service` block that seizes from individual `ResourcePool` elements (1 for each machine, with capacity 1). Link each `ResourcePool` to a `Downtime` element where you can specify your breakdown characteristics to any level of detail.

Check the help, example models and tutorials on those objects if you are not yet familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try it this way.

Comment: Glad the answer was helpful. Please upvote this answer as “useful” (up-arrow next to the answer) to help other users find it in the future as well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote for more info on how SOF works :)